# how to wrap nant build to ms build

Tags: .net, msbuild, nant

In my project we are using NAnt build to download the packages for the application. But now we are moving the code to **Odyssey** where Odyssey doesn't support the NAnt build. so is there any process to **wrap the NAnt build to MS Build**.

In Dev environment we are running the batch files manually in order to download all the binaries into our local machine. The batch file contains the Nant.exe

Regards,

Ram

Comment: Whatever NAnt does, you can do the same purely in MSBuild. So why cannot you convert your NAnt scripts to MSBuild? If you do have to wrap NAnt script, simply execute NAnt executable like executing any other command line utility.

Comment: @LexLi i need to wrap the NAnt build with MS Build, as per my understanding when i run the MS build it will internally execute the NAnt build. if it possible then provide me any wiki link for that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed it. instead of wrapping i found 2 options to resolve this issue.
  1)Created new solution and added third party required dll and exe then build solution.i can able to run the batch files without any problem but ,make sure to change the exe path in the batch file.                                                                         2) Create a package for the third party folder and deployed in the Artifactory repository and then downloading the file to required location will resolve the issue